# Add POST data when doing a TEMPORARY_REDIRECT from another POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

im developing a site that include a purchase screen. I will use a service similar to **PAYPAL**. I just need to send POST data to this service and the service will take care from that.

The thing is, there are some fields I want to hide. So inputs type hidden are not an option. So I added a simple form with just one data, **productId** and then redirect the POST with the added data.

Now the problem, that data is being sent as URL parameters(I can see those values in the URL in the browser). I want those values (in the example, userId and reference) as POST data. How could I achieve this?

The code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doPurchase", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doPurchase(Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "productId", required = true) String productId, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    //
    Product product = productRepository.findByProductCode(productId);
    //
    // DO STUFF...
    //
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:PAYMENT_SERVICE_URL");

    attributes.addAttribute("UserId", "USER_ID");
    attributes.addAttribute("Reference", "REF_ID");
    //
    // ETC ETC

    //
    request.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: Use flash attributes https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-flash-attributes

Comment: Aren't flash attributes stored in the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to redirect to do a POST request by `301`/`302`.
`307` can repeat the POST request, but you can not modify it.

Reference:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7

Some bypass methods:

1. Make your `PAYMENT_SERVICE_URL` accept both GET and POST requests.
2. Make a intermediate page accept the redirected GET request, and generate a HTML POST form to `PAYMENT_SERVICE_URL`, and auto submit the form by JavaScript.
3. If you are using `SpringFramework`, consider to use `Flash Attributes`: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-flash-attributes
4. If you really want to hide some parameters in a general way, you can store the values in a database table and pass the `id` of the row to your redirected page by GET request, and then load the parameters from the database table by `id`. Or, you can encrypt/decrypt the parameters.

Comment: This is sad to hear.. I already implemented method (2) so I guess I will have to keep it that way. Thanks!